# No se puede agregar una entrada de colección duplicada de tipo 'add' en c#

Tags: c#, .net, aspx

tengo el siguiente error

No se puede agregar una entrada de colección duplicada de tipo 'add' con un atributo de clave única 'name' establecido en 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

nose porque me marca eso las lineas que estoy ocupando son las siguientes

```
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

ahora cuando se las quito me marca lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces nose que sea ya tiene todos los permisos sin embargo no me agarra

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto al primer error este tiene que ver con reescribir una propiedad de configuración en una aplicación  que está por debajo del sitio web, probablemente en tu IIS tengas "Default Web Site" y a este le hiciste "Add Application", ahora tu "Default Web Site" debe tener configurado "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" por lo que no puedes configurarlo en tu propia aplicación, simplemente no está permitido. Borra las lineas de configuración en el web.config y se solucionará, también puedes eliminar estas configuraciones del sitio web padre, esto en IIS en la opción "HTTP Response Headers" o puedes hacerlo a mano desde web.config

Con respecto al segundo error es un error exclusivo de permisos sobre el web.config, quizás configurándolo lo cambiaste te tal manera que ya no se tiene permisos sobre el, dependiendo del Application Pool y el usuario configurado en el es que se le dan diferentes permisos ya sea a tu carpeta de la aplicación o a la carpeta inetpub. Esto depende de si la Application Pool Identity está configurada alguna "Built-in account" o una identidad de usuario específica

Comment: revise como mencionabas , tenia un usuario sin permisos y tambien le quite los acess origin y ya jalo